# How to reflect changes in preferences to class?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I created a simple class "User" that has an attribute String `username`. I'm assuming that since Android uses Java, I can create custom classes and it'll use them accordingly. In my SettingsActivity.java, I have:

```
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
    EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("username");
    editTextPref.setSummary(sharedPref.getString("username", "Default"));
    //sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
    // Get current summary
    Preference pref = findPreference(arg1);
    if(pref instanceof EditTextPreference){
        EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) pref;
        pref.setSummary(etp.getText());
        MainMenu.user.setName(etp.getText()); //This is where I try to update my class
    }
}
```

As of right now, whenever I change the value of my `EditTextPreference` widget, it doesn't update the public static user object located in `MainMenu`. Also, a followup question - since Android saves the preferences with each instance of app launch, how would I update my `User.username` String on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onPostCreate` remove the comment //

```
sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. Thanks a ton! In terms of the followup question, do you know how to access the preferences in order to retrieve the value for 'editTextPref' with key: "username" from another activity? I want to be able to retrieve the value of the preference without having to actually enter the Preferences Activity.

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); prefs.getString("username", ""):

Comment: Thanks a ton. You're a real time saver. I would've been up all night if not for you.